# Trying to bind whole Window to Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I'm trying to bind my whole window to a underlying usercontrol to let that usercontrol control parent window behaviour. For example i would like to close the parent window from the userControl. I want to create a custom TitleBar that i can reuse in other windows. I have tried using

```
<views:TitlebarUserCtrl BoundWindow="{Binding ElementName=Window1, Mode=OneWay}" ></views:TitlebarUserCtrl>
```

.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundCurrentWindow = DependencyProperty.Register("BoundWindow", typeof(Window), typeof(TitlebarUserCtrl), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
public Window BoundWindow
{
    get
    {
        return (Window)GetValue(BoundCurrentWindow);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(BoundCurrentWindow, value);
    }
}
```

But i only get a error. Any suggestions?

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to achive

Comment: I want to be able to close the window from the usercontrol for example. I want the to be able to call Window.Close() from the usercontrol.

Comment: Which errors? You code does work on my side. The window is bound. By the way - there is a convention to end dependency property with _property_. I.e `BoundWindowProperty`

Comment: The error is: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''The invocation of the constructor on type 'HWInterfaceChromaScan.Views.TitlebarUserCtrl' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '54' and line position '14'.' TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'HWInterfaceChromaScan.Views.TitlebarUserCtrl' threw an exception. ArgumentException: Default value type does not match type of property 'BoundWindow'.

Comment: Have you ever thought about creating your own Window Style / Template, then defining your own custom window control with your own personal hooks / labels / caption properties, etc?  Then you can have the visual look applied across the board and your custom window as the baseline for others?

Comment: I have, but it becomes overly complicated when using windowchrome and other stuff to get the same sense of feel. This would by far be the most modular and easy solution. If i only got it to work...

Comment: does my suggestion below not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all help.
I don't know what was not working. I cleared the obj folder and the error dissapeared. Edit: and I set UIPropertyMetadata("") to null - that seemed to fix it.

Here is the correct code:

```
C#
public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundCurrentWindow = DependencyProperty.Register("BoundWindowProperty", typeof(Window), typeof(TitlebarUserCtrl), null);
public Window BoundWindowProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return (Window)GetValue(BoundCurrentWindow);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BoundCurrentWindow, value);
        }
    }

WPF
<views:TitlebarUserCtrl BoundWindowProperty="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Comment: Thats the solution i recommended using find ancestor... but glad it helped you out

Comment: Yes i added that so it looks nicer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thats not how you use stack overflow. If you get help and it works for you you mark the answer as solutions

Comment: But your answer isn't the solution.Your proposed code works but it does not make any difference.My XAML worked too. The error was still there. I know how SO works - thanks!

Comment: I can do that in 3 hours... There is a time limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to your window by using a relative source thats looking for a Window-Type-control:

```
<views:TitlebarUserCtrl BoundWindow="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Comment: This works, but so does the xaml i have written above. Your solution is much nicer though. The problem was that i had to specify new UIPropertyMetadata("") to null instead.